# java application not reading properties file without setting the working folder in IDE

Tags: java, classpath, netbeans-7

I am developing a Java Application (not a web app, no server etc) using Netbeans 7.0.1 IDE.
Right now I have an issue with reading any properties /or any other file from my java class.

Here is what I am doing

```
 FileReader f = new FileReader( new File(args[0]) );
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(f);
```

in the argument I pass the file name like connector.properties (I have the file in the same package as this class). the project when run gives the error below

```
Can't load: connector.properties : Exception is: connector.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

why am I not able to read the properties file? whats the root of my classpath?

when I set the `'Working Folder'` (right clicking the project and selecting 'Run' section) to the package level like `C/complete/path/to/the/package` 
only then the properties file is read. 
I want to know why do I need to set the working folder in Netbeans project and how can I read the file without setting the working folder?

Comment: Are these properties for read-only, or are they read/write?

Comment: They are readonly for now.. Thanks

Comment: If they are read only, you can add them to one of the jars on the run-time class-path, and access them via URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using a class path reader to read your properties file. Your above code reads a hard path.

And, to read a properties file from a class path, you can use apache commons Configuration's file properties reader. There are several options there for reading properties file and the stream these input files are coming from e.g. Classpath.

Comment: Thanks..I also have a related issue with log4j.properties, Again I have to specify the whole path in the VM option when running the app so that log4j.properties is only read if I set this is VM options -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/c:/logconfig/log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to get a stream and then use `.load`:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)

to load the properties. This extends readily to reading any file in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your properties file in project folder because it's default working folder, not put in the package of class to be run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
String propertiesFileName = "config.properties";

InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);
properties.load(inputStream);
```

This code will do the trick when reading your properties file.